# where to get files for cd for clickonce

Tags: clickonce

I have created a clickonce deployment and published it to a website. I want to put the installer (version 1.0.0) on a cd for distribution to clients. A setup.exe was created in the route of the published folder but this is very small and cannot be the whole thing required for a cd.

I passed this on to a co developer who ran the setup.exe file alone and it told him required files are missing. Which files should I put on the cd and is there somewhere specific that these are located?

I selected the option that this installer was going onto a cd when going through the publishing wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need all the files in that folder, not just the setup.exe file.

> Application Files
>   autorun.inf
>   install.html
>   YourApp.application
>   setup.exe

In the Application Files folder, I believe you can omit the old versions.

Comment: This is correct. To expand on it, the setup.exe is more or less just a bootstrap style executable. The logic is defined in the other files.

Answer (score 1):

In the folder I see a setup.exe and myappname.application.
there are two other folders, one is called application files. the other is called windowsinstaller3_1.

Comment: You need everything that was output into the publish folder, not just the setup.exe. What exactly is in there will be different for every application, and different depending on what runtime you're targeting, etc. But if you copy everything there, then you should be fine.

Comment: So I also require all the versions of the deployment or just the most recent? there are several versions of the application now in the publish folder.

Comment: Ah think i got it> I reconfigured the deployment wizard to deploy to a local folder and it deployed everything i needed there. Before i was deploying to the same location as the website where updates can be downloaded from hence multiple versions. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the setup.exe is the prerequisites, not the applicaiton.  The .application file is the deployment manifest that is used to install the application.  It will in turn call setup.exe for any prerequisites you have set up.